# Totally Inaccessible

Tags: phrasing

"Totally inaccessible" is an accepted phrase, but I find it an odd one. If it were accessible in any way, then it wouldn't be "inaccessible," thus the "totally" part is superfluous.

Welcome your thoughts.

Comment: Isn't that true for most uses of 'totally in-/un-/non-/de-/etc'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bryan Garner has compiled a list of what he calls “uncomparable adjectives," the “best known” of which, he says, is *unique*--something either is or isn’t unique; there are no degrees of uniqueness. His list includes about 35 words, including *complete, entire, perpetual, universal*, etc.

However, he goes on to write that the general prohibition against using these words in comparative ways “should be tempered with reason.” He points out that the U.S. Constitution refers to a “more perfect union,” and that objections to that seem to him “pedantic.”

He does not include *inaccessible* in his list. He does make this general observation:

A few adjectives, such as *harmless*, are wrongly thought of as incomparable. It’s hopelessly donnish to insist that something is either *harmful* or *harmless* and that you can’t write *more harmful, more harmless*, or *relatively harmless*. The same is true of many other words.”

Presumably, he would say the same of *accessible/inaccessible*. Here is a [link](https://www1.maine.gov/dacf/parks/visitor_accessibility/access_guide.pdf) that makes clear that “accessibility,” in terms of complying with the ADA, can be measured by degrees.

Comment: This has been covered here before, but the reference is new. The juxtaposition of 'A few adjectives, such as _harmless_, are wrongly thought of as incomparable.... The same is true of many other words.' seems to spoil a reasonable article.

Answer (score 0):

English isn't logical. That's about all you need to explain it.

For example, you could use 'quite inaccessible' to describe something difficult to reach or understand.